# Maven: How to run a .java file from command line passing arguments

Tags: java, maven, arguments

I have the following problem. I would like to run `mvn` from command line for a `Main.java` file. `Main.java` accepts a parameter. **How do I do that from command line?**

I tried finding an example but I was not successful. Could someone help me by giving me an example of that?

I looked [here](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/) but didn't quite understand what I should do.

Also, **how do I execute that command from a different folder than the Main.java folder?**

for example the `Main.java` is located in `my/java/program/Main.java`. 
What should I put in

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="what to put here?" -Dexec.args="arg0 arg1 arg2"
```

Comment: What exactly did you not understand from the linked tutorial? Its pretty straight-forward. Please add to your question, the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is to call a java class from another java class. Normally I run that class from Eclipse. I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(""); to execute that class from another java program. But Main.class needs mvn to run. (I edited the question)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You could run: `mvn exec:exec -Dexec.args="arg1"`.

This will pass the argument *arg1* to your program.

You should specify the main class fully qualified, for example, a Main.java that is in a package test would need

```
mvn exec:java  -Dexec.mainClass=test.Main
```

By using the `-f` parameter, as decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478536/how-to-run-maven-from-another-directory-without-cd-to-project-dir), you can also run it from other directories.

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=test.Main -f folder/pom.xm
```

For multiple arguments, simply separate them with a space as you would at the command line.

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=test.Main -Dexec.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

For arguments separated with a <kbd>space</kbd>, you can group using `'argument separated with space'`  inside the quotation marks.

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=test.Main -Dexec.args="'argument separated with space' 'another one'"
```

Comment: yes, but how does it knows where the main.java file is located?

Comment: what if I do not have the pom.xml. I get the following error                              Cannot execute mojo: java. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.

Comment: A maven project requires a pom.xml, without this file, using maven makes little sense. So, maybe you want to create a maven project first? Then all the other solutions should work just fine.

Comment: Because I use Eclipse with the maven plugin i thought it was generated automatically but apparently I was wrong. I will take a look into it

Comment: How to pass arguments that contain spaces?

Comment: @Vanuan: I updated my answer, you can put the arguments with spaces in single quotes

Comment: Maven is removing my trailing double quote, failing with error org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: unbalanced quotes in "-Darg=value

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on... Please consider to post a new question and describe your problem in detail!

Comment: ok. Let say I send argument `-Dexec.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"` , 
so, how to print the three arguments in the code ?

it will store in what variable?

Answer (score 12):

Adding a shell script e.g. `run.sh` makes it much more easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export JAVA_PROGRAM_ARGS=`echo "$@"`
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="test.Main" -Dexec.args="$JAVA_PROGRAM_ARGS"
```

Then you are able to execute:

```
./run.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: This works great! Can you explain why this does not: -Dexec.args="$@"

Comment: `$@` stores all the arguments in a list of string wrapped in quotes. If you want to use it directly you may use `$*` - all arguments as a single string. Did you try this?

Answer (score 9):

In addition to running it with `mvn exec:java`, you can also run it with `mvn exec:exec`

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="java" -Dexec.args="-classpath %classpath your.package.MainClass"
```

Comment: Where would I put the Xmx argument in this case ?

Comment: Try putting it into `-Dexec.args`: `mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="java" -Dexec.args="-Xmx4g -classpath %classpath your.package.MainClass"`

Comment: I don't see where this will be better than the (IMO) straight forward approach of exec:java

Answer (score 0):

this aproach is half line command , half .pom file . you can put your args in a plugin inside the `<build> </build>` tag like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>%classpath your.package.MainClass</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>your_arg</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

now your arg is in the pom file . then just execute this in the command line

```
mvn clean compile exec:java
```

you can put many args :

```
       <arguments>
            <argument>your_arg1</argument>
            <argument>your_arg2</argument>
            <argument>your_arg3</argument>
        </arguments>
```