# spark-submit overriding default application.conf not working

Tags: apache-spark

I am building a jar which has `application.conf` under `src/main/resources` folder. However, I am trying to overwrite that while doing `spark-submit`. However it's not working.

following is my command

```
$spark_submit $spark_params $hbase_params \
    --class com.abc.xyz.MYClass \
    --files application.conf \
    $sandbox_jar flagFile/test.FLG \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=-Dconfig.file=application.conf"
```

`application.conf` - is located in same directory my jar file is.

Answer (score 0):

`-Dconfig.file=path/to/config-file` mayn't work due to internal cache on ConfigFactory. The documentation suggest to run `ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches()`.

The other way is following, which merges the supplied properties with existing properties available.

```
ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches()
val c = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(path-to-file + "/" + "application.conf"))
val config : Config = c.withFallback(ConfigFactory.load()).resolve
```

I think the best way to override the properties would be to supply them using `-D`. Typesafe gives highest priority to system properties, so -D will override reference.conf and application.conf.

Comment: not able to understand what you are trying to say. I have already provided that option. but it's not working

Comment: I missed your last line of code. Sorry abt that. I had similar issue and I loaded the file and merged with Config object. Please see modified answer.

Comment: could you expain who to handle `new File` to read from the parameter passed through maven

Comment: @Gaurang, one way is to keep application.conf in the application root (same directory as the jar). Then file path becomes `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: I mean.. when I pass it as maven parameter. how will it read the path here.

Comment: You can pass the path as -D into the Scala application and use my code to read the config file from that path. Here is an example of passing -D from maven - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108374/maven-how-to-run-a-java-file-from-command-line-passing-arguments/10108780

Answer (score 0):

Considering application.conf is properties file. There is other option, which can solve the same purpose of using properties file.

Not sure but packaging properties file with jar might not provide flexibility? Here keeping properties file separate from jar packaging, this will provide flexibility as, whenever if any property changes just replace new properties file instead of building and deploying whole jar.

This can be achieved as, keep your properties in properties file are prefix your property key with "spark."

```
spark.inputpath /input/path
spark.outputpath /output/path
```

Spark Submit command would be like,

```
$spark_submit $spark_params $hbase_params \
    --class com.abc.xyz.MYClass \
    --properties-file application.conf \
    $sandbox_jar flagFile/test.FLG
```

Getting properties in code like,

```
sc.getConf.get("spark.inputpath")       // /input/path
sc.getConf.get("spark.outputpath")      // /output/path
```

Not nessesary it will solve your problem though. But here just try to put another approach  to work.