# Can I use Maven without setting the Environment variable?

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I want to use Maven for my project.

In my office computer , I don't have the Admin privilege . Hence I am not able to set the "System Variable". 
I have access only to "User Variable" where I can set only the Java_Home.

Can I use **Maven** without adding the **M2_Home** and editing the **Path** variable ?

Comment: Is this on Windows? You should be able to just create a PATH variable in your user variables. In fact it should already be there. https://superuser.com/questions/133263/windows-7-user-specific-path

Comment: Yes, It is Windows. PATH variable is already there with the value %JAVA_HOME%/bin

Comment: So you can just add the maven bin path to it. No need to add any system variable at all.

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you are using it inside an ide or building project from terminal.

- If you are using an IDE, there is probably an embedded maven ( there is one inside Eclipse and Intellij IDEA)
- If you are building using CLI you can invoke maven using the full path 
  for instance :

  `/home/<your_folder>/tools/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn clean install` from your project path

Comment: I am using Eclipse  Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) and it has embedded Maven. When try to create a Maven Project, getting an error  "Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: etc......"

Comment: Can you check the maven installation inside your Eclipse ?
You can find it in the menu :

 Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations.

Make sure it is pointing to the embedded maven.

[see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316339/how-to-solve-maven-2-6-resource-plugin-dependency)

Comment: Check the thread in my previous comment and make sure , you are correctly setting your maven configuration.
Also check if you don't have a proxy blocking your eclipse from connecting to the maven repo.

Comment: @HaythemROUIS is this possible in `Windows` too?

Comment: Yes it does not depend on your OS.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the M2_HOME user variable even you are not an administrator, and the variable path is unnecessary, you could easily do the same task referencing the maven fullpath bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you just need to build your project from maven home actualy

[Here is an example from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478536/how-to-run-maven-from-another-directory-without-cd-to-project-dir)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have admin rights, simply set the path till Maven's bin in lets say MAVEN_HOME in user variables.
[image: MAVEN_HOME]

Then go to the Path variable in user variables and add MAVEN_HOME to it.
[image]

You are all set then, just go to command prompt and type mvn -version and you should be good with maven setup in your system.

Answer (score 0):

We can add .bat file and link it to cmd by default so whenever you open the terminal that code will execute and set your variable

You can refer more in detail [here](https://ashishontech.xyz/use-maven-without-admin-access-on-windows-os/).

**Update:**

For Windows 10 user can add detail for your account and doesn't require admin access. Search for below text in windows search bar

**Edit Environment variables for your Account**