# How to run a maven build from go lang code

Tags: maven, go, build, command

I am having the requirement of running a `maven` built using `go lang` without  installing `maven` to the running system. With the use of `os.exec` package in `go` I am able to run any program which is already defined in my `PATH` variable. But setting `M2_HOME` in `PATH` variable is not an option here and I am having the `maven` distribution extracted in specific location. According to the answer given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457619/can-i-use-maven-without-setting-the-environment-variable) it is possible to run a `maven` build by providing the specific location of `mvn`, how do I achieve the same from `go`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS? Did you try passing *full path* of the specific location to the `exec.Command` argument, e.g. `your/specific/folder/mvn`? Please provides your code snippets for executing the command, then if there is error, show us the error message.

Comment: Are you assuming that `maven` is already installed on the target machine or do you bundle the `maven` distribution with your software?

Comment: See also [os.ExpandEnv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ExpandEnv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the comment by @putu and with specifying the required `maven` goals one by one as separate arguments to the `exe.Command()` I was able to run `maven` build without installing `maven` or setting `M2_HOME` in `$PATH` variable. Below is the code snippet for anyone trying to achieve the same.

```
// Use os package to run the maven build using location where maven(headless) resides
func updateDistribution() error {
    command := exec.Command("apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/mvn", "clean", "install")
    command.Dir = "."
    output, err := command.Output()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", output)
    return nil
}
```