# Maven file and profile at the same time not working?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to execute a maven command like the following:

```
mvn clean install -f ../<some-path>/pom.xml -Pear -DskipTests
```

For some reason this command is not working correctly. The profile is not getting applied. What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried to set `clean install` at the end of the command? `mvn -f ../<some-path>/pom.xml -Pear -DskipTests clean install`

Comment: is the profile available/visible/known to `/<some-path>/pom.xml` ? otherwise maven console should output: `[WARNING] The requested profile "ear" could not...`, if the profile is properly applied, it should also be visible in the logs...

Comment: I think you need a space between -P and the profile you want to run. The command should work, so are you 100% sure the file is being picked up. Add -X to the command you'll get more detail.

Comment: is there reason why you call maven via `../..` instead of moving into the appropriate directory ?

Comment: So the actual thing is that i'm trying to execute the mvn clean install from a folder that is a subfolder of the project folder. But it doesn't work like i'm trying it. If i navigate to the project folder it works (without the -f). The command is also working, the profile is just not getting applied. xerx593 I'm not getting an error, Turing85 didn't help, emeraldjava I will try the -X

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm trying to running it via an automated script that is in a subfolder of the project

Comment: The command looks(*is*) ok! If you don't get [WARNING], then profile is applied! (your assumptions/expectations/observations could be wrong, or some ( thing/profile) interferes..?)

Comment: What do you mean by running within a subfolder ? First get it working on plain command line and afterwards automate it...

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe -f doesn't work as you think it does. See this answer: [How to run Maven from another directory (without cd to project dir)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478536/how-to-run-maven-from-another-directory-without-cd-to-project-dir)

If your project uses relative pom locations, this breaks.

See also: https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/common-bugs.html#Resolving_Relative_Paths

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ..
call mvn -DskipTests -Pear clean install
cd <some-path>
```

I did it like this now and it works. Thanks for @Adriaan Koster for the hint with the relative poms. That seems to have been it. And maybe i should use absolute paths instead :)